# Feature matrix from pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

Given the example from [scikit learn examples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py) using feature union having a pipeline like below. How is it possible to get the dimensions of the whole feature matrix after the pipeline executed?

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
# Extract the subject & body
('subjectbody', SubjectBodyExtractor()),

# Use FeatureUnion to combine the features from subject and body
('union', FeatureUnion(
    transformer_list=[

        # Pipeline for pulling features from the post's subject line
        ('subject', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='subject')),
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=50)),
        ])),

        # Pipeline for standard bag-of-words model for body
        ('body_bow', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='body')),
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
            ('best', TruncatedSVD(n_components=50)),
        ])),

        # Pipeline for pulling ad hoc features from post's body
        ('body_stats', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='body')),
            ('stats', TextStats()),  # returns a list of dicts
            ('vect', DictVectorizer()),  # list of dicts -> feature matrix
        ])),

    ],

    # weight components in FeatureUnion
    transformer_weights={
        'subject': 0.8,
        'body_bow': 0.5,
        'body_stats': 1.0,
    },
)),

# Use a SVC classifier on the combined features
('svc', SVC(kernel='linear')),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

FeatureUnion will only alter the columns of the data, so the number of rows remain same.

Now for getting the number of columns after the pipeline execution, there are multiple approaches:

1) Your current pipeline has SVC as last estimator. This does not change the shape of data, only fits the data. So you can use its attributes to get the number of features inputted to it from previous step.

As per [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html), you can use:

> support_vectors_ : array-like, shape = [n_SV, n_features]

The second dimension will represent the `n_features` that were inputted to SVC. You can access that by:

```
pipeline.named_steps['svc'].support_vectors_.shape
```

2) (Easier) You can duplicate the pipeline (leaving the last step (svc)) and then call `fit_transform()` on it.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
# Extract the subject & body
('subjectbody', SubjectBodyExtractor()),

# Use FeatureUnion to combine the features from subject and body
('union', FeatureUnion(
    transformer_list=[

        # Pipeline for pulling features from the post's subject line
        ('subject', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='subject')),
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=50)),
        ])),

        # Pipeline for standard bag-of-words model for body
        ('body_bow', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='body')),
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
            ('best', TruncatedSVD(n_components=50)),
        ])),

        # Pipeline for pulling ad hoc features from post's body
        ('body_stats', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='body')),
            ('stats', TextStats()),  # returns a list of dicts
            ('vect', DictVectorizer()),  # list of dicts -> feature matrix
        ])),

    ],

    # weight components in FeatureUnion
    transformer_weights={
        'subject': 0.8,
        'body_bow': 0.5,
        'body_stats': 1.0,
    },
)),
])
```

Then,

```
X_transformed = pipeline.fit_transform(X)
print(X_transformed.shape)
```